# Is it possible to have passwords configured per database or per host in .my.cnf

Tags: mysql, configuration

I have the following in my `~/.my.cnf`

```
[client]
password="somepass"
```

but this is not the password I use for every user@host/database I connect to. Is there some way to specify in the config different passwords for different things so I don't have to type them in?

Comment: [User @DTest answered a question like this in May of this year][1] 


  [1]: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2820/why-dont-my-my-cnf-settings-work/2822#2822

Answer (score 83, accepted):

As I answered [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2820/why-dont-my-my-cnf-settings-work/2822#2822), you can add a section for each user/host/db you connect to using the syntax in your `~/.my.cnf`:

```
[clienthost1]   # Note: client + host1
user=myuser
password=mypass
database=dbname
host=server.location.com
```

Once this is in your user's `.my.cnf`, you can utilize it by doing this on a command line:

```
$ mysql --defaults-group-suffix=host1
```

Comment: As promised, +1 !!!

Comment: Could you explain this --defaults-group-suffix?

Comment: Nice. It took me a while to figure the rest out from here but for an mysql Cron backup, I can now use 

mysqldump --defaults-group-suffix=host1 -P 3306 -h 111.0.0.xxx --ssl -u db_usr db_name > /home/myaccount/backups/db_name_$(echo $(date '+\%Y\%m\%d').sql.gz)

to create a gzipped backup. Thank you!

Comment: Note: if you put this in a global my.cnf, such as `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, but have a user-defined `.my.cnf` with `[client]` defined therein, the latter will override settings in the global file! boo.

Comment: Note that MariaDB’s manpage falsely states that a suffix of `x` will read the section `[client_x]` but in reality you need the suffix `_x` for that

Comment: @DanielBöhmer which man page does state that? I'm genuinely curious because there's little info about it aside from one sentence for `--defaults-group-suffix` option.

Comment: @woky: I can't recall right now where I found this statement. But it was when I used MariaDB from its official .deb repositories under Debian 9 or 10.

Answer (score 11):

The other answer is correct. Unfortunately `mysqladmin` doesn't support `--defaults-group-suffix` (at least not the version I'm using).

Hence I resorted to using `--defaults-file=HOST.cnf` instead, which works for `mysql`, `mysqladmin` and `mysqldump`.

Comment: Adding this to my .bash_profile made it even easier: `alias my-host='mysql --defaults-file=HOST.cnf'`

Answer (score 10):

Put clear passwords in text files is not recommended since mysql 5.6.6.

You can use `mysql_config_editor` to save passwords encrypted also to provide different passwords for different connections https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html

Comment: Security by obscurity...

Comment: +1 for mentioning mysql_config_editor

Comment: Until this program is (1) backported to previous versions, (2) allows automated password deployment (ie, not forcing passwords to be read on TTY), I do not recommend this method.

Comment: Does MariaDB have comparable support or feature to match mysql_config_editor?

Comment: @JeremyHajek No, it does not, and likely never will because the MariaDB devs point out that only provides a false sense of improved security: [MySQL 5.6: Security through Complacency?](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/mysql-56-security-through-complacency)